# Matching closing <table> tag using regex

Tags: xml, regex

I need to find `<table>` tags in xml data-dictionary file. The criteria is the table Element must contain a word `tax` or `Tax`.

For that, I have tried to match the closing html `table` tag.

`<table\b[^>]*>(.*?)</table>` and  `<table[^>]*>[^(<\/table>)]*` but it is not working.

I found for parsing xml we have to use XML Parser rather than regex. But I am very comfortable with regex as of now, so I want to finish it using regex this time.

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: Don't use regex to parse XML, use an XML parser

Comment: @h2ooooooo I am using java. But I want to find matches, with notepad, using regex search option.

Answer (score 3):

Use a DOM XML PARSER and use the getElementsByTagName() function to match table tags and getTextContent() to get the contents of the tag to match the word *tax* or *Tax*. Kindly refrain from using regular expression as it is a bad practice to parse XML with regex.

For an easy tutorial refer:  http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-read-xml-file-in-java-dom-parser/